# Spring-Data-Mongodb - How to look for a document, based on a field value of a document referenced within?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Here are my two classes :

```
@Document(collection="people")
public class Person {    

    // Data.
    @Id
    private ObjectId Id;

    @Field("email")
    private String email;

    @DBRef
    private List<Entity> entities;    


    /* Getters and setters removed to keep this question simple. */
}
```

And, here is my entity class.

```
@Document(collection = "entities")
public class Entity {    

    @Id
    private ObjectId Id;    

    @DBRef
    private List<Person> people;    

    /* Getters and setters removed to keep question simple. */
}
```

And here is my mongoRepository :

```
public interface EntityRepository extends MongoRepository<Entity, String>{
    List<Entity> findByPeople_email(String email);
}
```

I think you can see what I want to do here - I want to query the mongo database, and get back all entities attached to a user where the email address matches the one I provide. I keep getting stuck in an SQL mindset here, and thinking I can just do something like :

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE email="<email_here>"
```

But obviously that is not the case! Anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: That is not possible by design as [DBRef](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#dbref-explanation) can only be accessed by its `_id`. You have other options. You can use [embedded documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)  to query directly or  use                          [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)  to join two collections in aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Yeah, and embedded documents don't really work well for my spec. What if I got my user by email, pulled the ID, then pulled the entities out for that via the ID? Would that work?

Comment: Yeah. Try pulling the user by email it will pull all the entities because the `DBRef` are loaded eagerly.

Comment: Would that be a good solution? Or would it be bad?

Comment: It depends. Couple of points. You can try defining lazy db ref and pass the selected ids for loading. Under the hood, spring bulk loads [db refs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/DefaultDbRefResolver.html#bulkFetch-java.util.List-)